# Циклы for ... in

Tags: python, python-3.x, pascal, pascalabc.net

Решал задачку ЕГЭ,на питоне.Дан код из Паскаля:

```
  for i := 1 to N-1 do
    for j := i+1 to N do
      writeln(j);
```

Пытался сделать такое на Питоне ,только траблы в том,что не получается сделать,чтобы j принимало значение i+1

```
for i in range(n):
    j=(i+1)
    for j in range(n):
        print(j)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(i+1,n+1):
        print(j)
```

Comment: Благодарю,заработало
Можете ответить на вопрос
Цикл for в паскале работает так:
for "от" to "до"
Цикл for в питоне работает так:
for "переменная для записи значений" in range("от","до")???

Comment: @MiniSkill В паскале от "равно началу" и "пока меньше или равно концу". В питоне range() - генерирует список от "равно началу" и "пока меньше конца".